# How to fit image into bootstrap panel-body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to fit image into bootstrap panel-body? 
I am using img tag. I tried to do max-height:100% and max-width: 100% but no luck.
Is there any way to fit image to panel-body without specifying actual height and width.
following is my code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container" id="project_info">



    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Medical Data Visualization</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img src="resource/Medical_visualization.jpg" class="img-rounded" id="Panel_Image">
                </div>
            </div>


    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks.........

Comment: If you are using img tag then we cant accurately fit img to the parent. Use css background property

Comment: otherwise use only max-height 100%

Comment: is that fixed your issue?

Comment: No. I tried background property but image is not scaling to panel body.

Comment: Shall i post as answer using background property?

Comment: Thanks  its working. I used  img-responsive class as mentioned by Aravind bellow.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the img-responsive class of bootstrap

```
<div class="panel-body">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="resource/Medical_visualization.jpg" class="img-rounded" id="Panel_Image">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
.panel-body{
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(your-image.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

also remove img tag. change the height as per req.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using image as inline background. I have created a snippet. please check

```css
.panel-body {position: relative}

.panel-body .image-holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container" id="project_info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Medical Data Visualization</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="image-holder" style="background: url(http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/nature/nature-02.jpg)"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the image above the panel body before the heading.

```html
<div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">The Title</div>
        </div>
        <img src="" width="100%" />
        <div class="panel-body">
              ...
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```